# Delete on of the id in mysql varchar

Tags: mysql, sql

I cannot find the way how i can delete one of the stored ids in varchar column.

```
id         fieldid
1          ,5,13,15,66,443,
```

how i can delete, lets say 15 from this field id?

Comment: Fix your data structure.  Storing integer values in a string is not the SQLish way to store lists of values.

Comment: Well yeah, i've read about it somewhere, but the problem is - i didnt do this myself and i cannot change it...

Comment: I would really accept with @GordonLinoff a very bad architecture of table schema for storing data separated by `commas`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct logic is:

```
UPDATE <your_table_name>
    SET fieldid = REPLACE(fieldid, ',15,', ',')
---------------------------------------^----^ these commas a really important
    WHERE id = 1;
```

However, storing list of numbers of strings is bad, bad, bad in SQL:

- Numbers should be declares as numbers, not strings.
- Foreign key relationships should be explicitly declared.
- SQL has lousy string processing functionality.
- Queries on string lists cannot be optimized.
- And there are more reasons.

Sometimes, you are stuck with someone else's really, really, really bad design decisions.

Comment: Its working! Thanks mate.
Yeah i gotta work sometimes on some projects that were developed by people that are not working here anymore, and i just started as a junior... I feel like sometimes people like to overthink things...

Answer (score 1):

You gave give `REPLACE` a shot though

```
DECLARE @Test VARCHAR(50)

SET @Test = ',5,13,15,66,443,'

SELECT REPLACE(@Test,'15,','')
```

### Result

```
,5,13,66,443,
```

Comment: You should put an `UPDATE` in the answer so it helps the OP.

Comment: @GordonLinoff actually I wanted him to figure it out :). Though no issues I see #Twyly has posted it.

Answer (score 1):

Check with ORACLE

```
UPDATE <your_table_name>
  SET fieldid = REPLACE(fieldid,',15','')
 WHERE id = 1;
```

This will replace ',15' with empty string. Like remove from string.